# Firebase deploy keeps giving me an Error: Parse Error in remoteconfig.template.json

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to deploy a web app with firebase but every time I run deploy I keep getting this error

```
Error: Parse Error in remoteconfig.template.json:

No data, empty input at 1:1

^
File: "remoteconfig.template.json"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a reference to a `remoteconfig.template.json` in your `firebase.json` files, but that template doesn't exist. This will typically look like:

```
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
```

The solution is to find this section in your `firebase.json` file, and remove it.

Comment: I have to disagree with this approach because I believe the file exists but is empty. The suggested approach would break the reference to the ``remoteconfig`` defined template file (in that case ``remoteconfig.template.json``) going forward.I would suggest to avoid removing the mentionned section from the ``firebase.json`` file but instead add ``{ }`` in the template file, which would allow the ``firebase deploy`` to work.

Comment: Sounds like a great alternative answer @BenjaminRAIBAUD :)

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because in your firebase init you included (or said yes to) remote config. For it to work with deploy you must add at least one parameter in the file remoteconfig.template.json like so;

```
{
    "example_minimum_score_for_level_2": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BenjaminRAIBAUD commented, if `remoteconfig.template.json` is empty, try adding `{ }` to the file. That worked for me.